# How to use scala.collection.JavaConverters in intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I want to use java nio in scala,I try to convert this code to scala:

```
ServerSocketChannel ssChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
int port = 9001;
ssChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
Selector selector = Selector.open();

ssChannel.configureBlocking(false);
ssChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT); 

while (true) {
selector.select();
Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
for (SelectionKey key : keys) {
  if (key.isAcceptable()) { 
    ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key
    .channel();
    SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
    sc.configureBlocking(false);
    sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ); 
  }
  if(key.isReadable()){ 
    SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    sc.read(buffer);

    buffer.flip();
    sc.write(buffer);
  }
}
keys.clear();
}
}
```

when I copy this code to intellij,intellij ask me if I want convert this code to scala,I agree.

then intellij

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._,
```

and tell me a red error

I use scala 2.12.7 in intellij,I check the scala api doc,JavaConversion has deprecated,so I

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

but intellij tell me it's deprecated,let me use

```
scala.jdk.CollectionConverters
```

when I import this,there is still error in the line:

```
key.isAcceptable
```

so how to convert this code in intellij?Thanks!

My intellij version is 2018.3.4 Community Edition

Comment: I download the new intellij 2019.1.3,but intellij also tell me "Can't resolve symbol JavaConversions".OK,I should use netty.

Comment: If you are more comfortable with Java, you can also just drop `.java` source files into your Scala project, they will be compiled as well, and you can call them from Scala code. That way you can migrate/rewrite gradually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty naive, line-by-line, translation of your Java code.

I don't know if it does what you want, I haven't done much NIO, or meddled in Java-land, for quite some time, but it does compile.

```
import java.nio.channels.{ServerSocketChannel,Selector,SelectionKey,SocketChannel}
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import collection.JavaConverters._

val ssChannel :ServerSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open()
val port = 9001
ssChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port))
val selector :Selector = Selector.open()

ssChannel.configureBlocking(false)
ssChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)

while (true) {
  selector.select()
  val keys :collection.mutable.Set[SelectionKey] = selector.selectedKeys().asScala
  for (key <- keys) {
    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
      val ssc :ServerSocketChannel = key.channel().asInstanceOf[ServerSocketChannel]
      val sc :SocketChannel = ssc.accept()
      sc.configureBlocking(false)
      sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ)
    }
    if(key.isReadable()){
      val sc :SocketChannel = key.channel().asInstanceOf[SocketChannel]
      val buffer :ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024)
      sc.read(buffer)
      buffer.flip()
      sc.write(buffer)
    }
  }
  keys.clear()
}
```

You'll note that, in this example, `JavaConverters` is only used to get a Scala `mutable.Set` from the Java `Set`, and that's only needed in order to make the `foreach()` (internal to the for-comprehension) work.